# LLVM compiler infrastructure for VLIW architectures

Tags: cross-platform, llvm, epic, vliw

Do you know how strong [VLIW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word) architectures (or [EPIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicitly_parallel_instruction_computing), like Itanium) support exists in LLVM compiler infrastructure?

Are there good documents/slides materials on this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no good VLIW support in the base LLVM at the moment. / 2010-11

Some useful posts:
http://old.nabble.com/VLIW-Scheduling-td857833.html

http://old.nabble.com/vliw-compatability-td27935919.html

UPDATE / 2012-01

LLVM added (seems [after 3.0 release](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=145629); by [Anshuman Dasgupta](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.cvs/103519)) initial support of an "VLIW packetizer" aka DFApacketizer to target-independent codegenerator support infrastructure:
http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#vliw_packetizer

> To generate tables for a VLIW target, add *Target*GenDFAPacketizer.inc as a target to the Makefile in the target directory. The exported API provides three functions:

- DFAPacketizer::clearResources(),
- DFAPacketizer::reserveResources(MachineInstr *MI), and
- DFAPacketizer::canReserveResources(MachineInstr *MI).

> These functions allow a target packetizer to add an instruction to an existing packet and to check whether an instruction can be added to a packet. See [`llvm/CodeGen/DFAPacketizer.h`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/DFAPacketizer_8h_source.html) for more information.

[Machine Instruction Bundle in LLVM](http://markmail.org/message/4u2qlphy3wfjwjkj#query%3a+page:1+mid%3af23kb5dsavyoy2uk+state%3aresults) thread by Evan Cheng in mailing list    com.googlegroups.llvm-dev from dec 2 2011, describing basic LLVM VLIW (Bundle) support. They are [planned](http://llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#whatsnew) to be in LLVM 3.1, and are [documented here](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#machineinstrbundle).

Also, in 3.1 "new TableGen infrastructure to support bundling for Very Long Instruction Word (VLIW) architectures." is added.

There are some VLIW compilers based on LLVM today; but target-independent (generic) VLIW support is in the very beginning of its long path.

UPDATE 2012/12

There are some slides from Quic: http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Larin-Trick-Scheduling.pdf

Comment: There are some VLIW targets listed in LLVM's Triple.h: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Triple_8h_source.html ...